# Add shortcuts for LLDB debugger in Xcode for Swift debugging

Tags: swift, xcode, lldb

I have just started learning visual debugging in Xcode and I would like to know if I can simplify the debugging process. A typical debugging session starts with:

```
$ e -l Swift -- import UIKit
$ e -l Swift -- let $myLabel = unsafeBitCast(..., UIView.self)
$ e -l Swift -- // use $myLabel
```

Is there any way I can omit:

```
$ e -l Swift --
```

And change it to, for example:

```
$ SDB
```

So I can write:

```
$ SDB import UIKit
$ SDB let $myLabel = unsafeBitCast(..., UIView.self)
$ SDB // use $myLabel
```

I am not very familiar with talking to the command line. I think I need to add some command to `PATH`? But I am confused where this `PATH` is for LLDB debugging.

How can I add a shortcut for LLDB debugging in Xcode?

Sidequestion: what is the `-l` for before `Swift` in above commands? This command does not work: `man lldb` so I can not look it up and Google doesn't help me also. Without the `-l`, debugging fails. Same applies for the `$` sign before every variable. I do not know why I need to add that.

Comment: `l` means language.

Comment: @matt A that sounds logical :)

Comment: lldb documents its commands with its built-in help system - accessed by the "help" and "apropos" commands.  So running the command "help e" will show you all the options to the "expression" command.